# requestNewPublishPermissions for Facebook SDK in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

Currently I call `requestNewPublishPermissions` to request the `publish_stream` permission.

Is there a way for me to see if the user has already authorized that permission so I don't need to ask it again?

I thought `Session.isPublishPermission("publish_stream")` might be that, but it doesn't seem to match the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the user has already authorized a permission, you have to call the API:

```
\GET /me/permissions
```

You'll get the response in the format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1,
      "basic_info": 1,
      "public_profile": 1,
      "publish_stream": 1,
      "user_notes": 1,
      "user_friends": 1
    }
  ],
}
```

If this have the `"publish_stream": 1` permission that means the user has authorized the app to publish on his behalf.

**Code** (if using android SDK)-

```
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/permissions",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```